# Merge these 2 arrays

Tags: javascript

I have an array I start out with:

```
var array1 = [{"key":{"id":1,"kind":"Table","path":["Table",1]},"data":{"txt":"some txt","modified":1461294950,"cat1":"a1","permission":"n"}},
{"key":{"id":2,"kind":"Table","path":["Table",2]},"data":{"txt":"some txt","modified":1461294953,"cat1":"a1","permission":"n"}},
{"key":{"id":3,"kind":"Table","path":["Table",3]},"data":{"txt":"some txt","modified":1461294954,"cat1":"a1","permission":"n"}},
{"key":{"id":4,"kind":"Table","path":["Table",4]},"data":{"txt":"some txt","modified":1461294954,"cat1":"a1","permission":"n"}},
{"key":{"id":5,"kind":"Table","path":["Table",5]},"data":{"txt":"some txt","modified":1461294954,"cat1":"a1","permission":"n"}}];
```

This array has 5 elements. I then from my server get 5 more results. I would like to append this new array to the existing.

So I receive this from my server:

```
var server_response = [{"key":{"id":6,"kind":"Table","path":["Table",6]},"data":{"txt":"some txt","modified":1461294954,"cat1":"a1","permission":"n"}},
{"key":{"id":7,"kind":"Table","path":["Table",7]},"data":{"txt":"some txt","modified":1461294954,"cat1":"a1","permission":"n"}},
{"key":{"id":8,"kind":"Table","path":["Table",8]},"data":{"txt":"some txt","modified":1461294954,"cat1":"a1","permission":"n"}},
{"key":{"id":9,"kind":"Table","path":["Table",9]},"data":{"txt":"some txt","modified":1461294955,"cat1":"a1","permission":"n"}},
{"key":{"id":10,"kind":"Table","path":["Table",10]},"data":{"txt":"some txt","modified":1461294955,"cat1":"a1","permission":"n"}}];
```

So to merge them I go:

```
console.log(array1.push(server_response);
```

But I get the following result:

> [{"key":{"id":1,"kind":"Table","path":["Table",1]},"data":{"txt":"some
>   txt","modified":1461294950,"cat1":"a1","permission":"n"}},{"key":{"id":2,"kind":"Table","path":["Table",2]},"data":{"txt":"some
>   txt","modified":1461294953,"cat1":"a1","permission":"n"}},{"key":{"id":3,"kind":"Table","path":["Table",3]},"data":{"txt":"some
>   txt","modified":1461294954,"cat1":"a1","permission":"n"}},{"key":{"id":4,"kind":"Table","path":["Table",4]},"data":{"txt":"some
>   txt","modified":1461294954,"cat1":"a1","permission":"n"}},{"key":{"id":5,"kind":"Table","path":["Table",5]},"data":{"txt":"some
>   txt","modified":1461294954,"cat1":"a1","permission":"n"}},**[{"key":{"id":6,"kind":"Table","path":["Table",6]},"data":{"txt":"some
>   txt","modified":1461294954,"cat1":"a1","permission":"n"}},{"key":{"id":7,"kind":"Table","path":["Table",7]},"data":{"txt":"some
>   txt","modified":1461294954,"cat1":"a1","permission":"n"}},{"key":{"id":8,"kind":"Table","path":["Table",8]},"data":{"txt":"some
>   txt","modified":1461294954,"cat1":"a1","permission":"n"}},{"key":{"id":9,"kind":"Table","path":["Table",9]},"data":{"txt":"some
>   txt","modified":1461294955,"cat1":"a1","permission":"n"}},{"key":{"id":10,"kind":"Table","path":["Table",10]},"data":{"txt":"some
>   txt","modified":1461294955,"cat1":"a1","permission":"n"}}]**]

As you can see it adds the second array as an actual array to the first array. I just want the content of the server response to be added (essentially so there should be no square brackets). I know I could do this using regex, but this does not seem like a good solution. How can I merge these arrays?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `concat`

```
var array1 = [{"key":{"id":1,"kind":"Table","path":["Table",1]},"data":{"txt":"some txt","modified":1461294950,"cat1":"a1","permission":"n"}},
{"key":{"id":2,"kind":"Table","path":["Table",2]},"data":{"txt":"some txt","modified":1461294953,"cat1":"a1","permission":"n"}},
{"key":{"id":3,"kind":"Table","path":["Table",3]},"data":{"txt":"some txt","modified":1461294954,"cat1":"a1","permission":"n"}},
{"key":{"id":4,"kind":"Table","path":["Table",4]},"data":{"txt":"some txt","modified":1461294954,"cat1":"a1","permission":"n"}},
{"key":{"id":5,"kind":"Table","path":["Table",5]},"data":{"txt":"some txt","modified":1461294954,"cat1":"a1","permission":"n"}}];
var server_response = [{"key":{"id":6,"kind":"Table","path":["Table",6]},"data":{"txt":"some txt","modified":1461294954,"cat1":"a1","permission":"n"}},
{"key":{"id":7,"kind":"Table","path":["Table",7]},"data":{"txt":"some txt","modified":1461294954,"cat1":"a1","permission":"n"}},
{"key":{"id":8,"kind":"Table","path":["Table",8]},"data":{"txt":"some txt","modified":1461294954,"cat1":"a1","permission":"n"}},
{"key":{"id":9,"kind":"Table","path":["Table",9]},"data":{"txt":"some txt","modified":1461294955,"cat1":"a1","permission":"n"}},
{"key":{"id":10,"kind":"Table","path":["Table",10]},"data":{"txt":"some txt","modified":1461294955,"cat1":"a1","permission":"n"}}];
console.log(array1.concat(server_response));
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for! This is what I thought push did, but look like not.

Answer (score 2):

Try the concat method...

```
MergedArray=Array1.concat(Array2,Array3,Array4);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to append this new array to the existing.

You can use `Array.prototype.push.apply` if you do not wish to create a new array. `Array.prototype.push.apply` will update your `array1` with the content of `server_push`.

See below:

```js
var array1 = [{"key":{"id":1,"kind":"Table","path":["Table",1]},"data":{"txt":"some txt","modified":1461294950,"cat1":"a1","permission":"n"}},
{"key":{"id":2,"kind":"Table","path":["Table",2]},"data":{"txt":"some txt","modified":1461294953,"cat1":"a1","permission":"n"}},
{"key":{"id":3,"kind":"Table","path":["Table",3]},"data":{"txt":"some txt","modified":1461294954,"cat1":"a1","permission":"n"}},
{"key":{"id":4,"kind":"Table","path":["Table",4]},"data":{"txt":"some txt","modified":1461294954,"cat1":"a1","permission":"n"}},
{"key":{"id":5,"kind":"Table","path":["Table",5]},"data":{"txt":"some txt","modified":1461294954,"cat1":"a1","permission":"n"}}];

var server_response = [{"key":{"id":6,"kind":"Table","path":["Table",6]},"data":{"txt":"some txt","modified":1461294954,"cat1":"a1","permission":"n"}},
{"key":{"id":7,"kind":"Table","path":["Table",7]},"data":{"txt":"some txt","modified":1461294954,"cat1":"a1","permission":"n"}},
{"key":{"id":8,"kind":"Table","path":["Table",8]},"data":{"txt":"some txt","modified":1461294954,"cat1":"a1","permission":"n"}},
{"key":{"id":9,"kind":"Table","path":["Table",9]},"data":{"txt":"some txt","modified":1461294955,"cat1":"a1","permission":"n"}},
{"key":{"id":10,"kind":"Table","path":["Table",10]},"data":{"txt":"some txt","modified":1461294955,"cat1":"a1","permission":"n"}}];

Array.prototype.push.apply(array1, server_response);

document.body.textContent = JSON.stringify(array1);
```